# How to create some query mechanism - Object oriented design

Tags: java, oop

I have some set of objects (class MyObject). Each object is identified by three strings named `type`, `instance`, `name`. These strings I will call `description`.
I want to create a mechanism to get the proper objects based on parts of the `description` or the complete `description`.
If I have the following objects:

```
Object 1. has type:myType; instance:myInstance; name:myName;
Object 2. has type:myType; instance:myInstance2; name:myName2;
Object 3. has type:myType2; instance:myInstance3; name:myName3;
Object 4. has type:myType2; instance:myInstance3; name:myName4;
```

I want that

```
get("myType") returns objects 1. and 2.
get("myType").get("myInstance") returns object 1.
get("myType2").get("myInstance3") returns objects 3. and 4.
get("myType2").get("myInstance3").get("myName4") returns object 4.
```

My colleague explained me how to achieve this but I did not understand it :|
He sketched the following diagram

[image: diagram draft]

Where on this diagram is place for `MyObject`? Should `MyObject` aggregate `A`, `B`, `C` or vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

Your colleague's diagram looks to be just an illustration of this call:

```
get("myType2").get("myInstance3").get("myName4") returns object 4.
```

If we rewrite that, then it sort of looks like...

```
A = get("myType2");
B = A.get("myInstance3");
C = B.get("myName4");
```

But whatever A/B/C is, its class needs to be able to hold multiple items, so it sounds like you need a MyObjectCollection<> class, and implement get() (which returns a MyObjectCollection<>) for it.

```
MyObjectCollection<MyObject> A = get("myType2");
MyObjectCollection<MyObject> B = A.get("myInstance3")
MyObjectCollection<MyObject> C = B.get("myName4")
```

And then C will contain MyObject 4.